# What will happen to event listeners after i will update `src` in Audio element ? (React)

Tags: html, reactjs, audio, redux, react-redux

Is it efficient to handle song changes in that way ?
What will happen to event listeners after i will update `src` and it will rerender `Audio` element ?

```
<audio
  ref={ref => (this._player = ref)}
  onEnded={() => this.next()}
  src={this.props.active_song.audio_file}
  onCanPlayThrough={this.onCanPlay.bind(this)}
  onTimeUpdate={this.listenProgress.bind(this)}
  onPause={this.onPause.bind(this)}
  onPlay={this.onPlay.bind(this)}
  autoPlay={this.state.play}
  preload="none"
>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will happen to the event listeners.

When you change the `src` dynamically, only the url source is been changed not the loaded audio stream.

To play the new audio, you have to load and play it.

```
this._player.pause();
this._player.load();
this._player.play();
```